# How do I make my gatsby.js site mobile friendly?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, gatsby

this is more of a general question. I built my portfolio using gatsby.js and React but I'm not sure how to make the website mobile friendly? I searched online but didn't find much of the information that I need. Could someone give me a little more information? or point me in the right direction?